# How can pandas str.extract method returns more match from my list?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have rows like this in a pandas series object:

```
['Blazic M.', 'Boli F.', 'Botka E.', 'Civic E.', 'Dibusz D. (K)', 'Kharatin I.', 'N. Tokmac', 'Otigba K.', 'Sigér D.', 'Vécsei B.', 'Zubkov O.']`
```

it is a <class 'str'>

I want with .str.extract('[\w,]') to only match the alphabetic characters and commas but i only got the first letter from all the row. Where did i make the mistake?

here is my full code: import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv', encoding='latin', names=['Csapat','Játékosok'])
jatekosok = df['Játékosok'].str.extract('[\w,]')

print(jatekosok)
```

here is the original series which i work with before the extraction:

```
0      ['Blazic M.', 'Boli F.', 'Botka E.', 'Civic E....
1      ['Berecz Zs.', 'Cseri T.', 'Farkas D.', 'Jurin...
2      ['Deutsch L.', 'Gyurcsó Á.', 'Hadzhiev K.', 'K...
3      ['Batik B.', 'Gazdag D.', 'George M.', 'Hidi P...
4      ['Adeniji T.', 'Bényei B.', 'Ferenczi J.', 'Ki...
                             ...
391    ['Böde D.', 'Fejes A.', 'Fejõs Á.', 'Hahn J.',...
392    ['Cseri T.', 'Farkas D.', 'Karnitskiy A.', 'Ka...
393    ['Babati B.', 'Barczi D.', 'Bedi B.', 'Demjén ...
394    ['B. Pauljevic', 'Burekovic D.', 'Koszta M.', ...
395    ['Hadzhiev K.', 'Hegedûs L. (K)', 'Henty E.', ...
```

Comment: you can try using `extractall()` instead of `extract` or use `str.findall()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findall`:

```
>> pd.Series(['Blazic M., 123 Boli F.']).str.findall('([a-zA-Z,])')
0    [B, l, a, z, i, c, M, ,, B, o, l, i, F]
dtype: object
```